# How can I add bootstrap's icon to button_to in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

My original code is

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', girl, confirm: 'Are you sure?', :disable_with => 'deleting...', method: :delete, :class => 'btn-mini btn-danger btn'  %>
```

I'd like to add an icon in front of the word "Destroy".

icon tag is this

```
<i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>
```

How can I do that??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using a block

```
<%= link_to girl, confirm: 'Are you sure?', disable_with: 'deleting...', method: :delete, class: 'btn-mini btn-danger btn' do %>
  <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i> Destroy
<% end %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Thanks!! I changed it to     <td>
  <%= button_to 'Destroy', girl, confirm: 'Are you sure?', :disable_with => 'deleting...', method: :delete, :class => 'btn-mini btn-danger btn' do %>
     <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>Destroy 
  <% end %>
 </td> but it's still the same no change...

Comment: On http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons it says "When using beside strings of text, as in buttons or nav links, be sure to leave a space after the <i> tag for proper spacing."

Comment: Also rails might be escaping the html, wrap it in a string and pass to the raw function if needed

Comment: You need to remove the first arg to button_to, that is in the block now, Also you might need to use link_to, instead of button_to i think they both support block